# How do you download a specified group of orders?

Tags: integration, shopify

I am a developer for a 3PL and am building an integration that only uses the shopify api to download and update orders.  I need a solution that will allow the following:

1) a store to specify orders that are ready for download

2) my app to download only those orders

3) my app to change those orders to a state that will not be downloaded

The closest I have got so far is to use order tags, which I can do all but #2 with.  Do you know how to download orders filtered by a certain tag?  OR is there a better api-based solution to this full set of requirements?

Comment: Can't you just use a webhook that runs each time an order is completed? then you don't have to tag anything.

Answer (score 1):

you can use api [webhook](http://docs.shopify.com/api/webhook) to get the orders from shopify(for step 1 and step 2), then you can use note_attributes from order properties(for step 3)

---

This is what i understood from your question

1)order is created from shopping cart(when an order is created, the order note_attributes is empty, so you can validate this is empty or contains any field with name order_checked and value 'yes' ) -> "financial_status": "pending"

2)Order status is changed by store owner(I suppose that you going to download orders paid) -> "financial_status": "paid"

3)you can create webhooks to order create|update|delete, then use webhook for some named webhook option to send data to you web service, process data and then update order and set note_attributes[{ "name" : "order_checked" }, { "value" : "yes" }] instead of using tags

4)another way would be using cronjob from your webhosting and apply your step2 validating order note_attributes (you can also use this for ensure that the orders are always checked)

Comment: That might work, here are some issues I am worried about with that solution:
- from what I understand, I could not get the granularity I'm looking for (ex: send the order to me when they tag it "send_to_nathan"), the most specific I am seeing would be to have it send me any order when the data changes. Am I missing a more targeted solution?
- what happens if my api happens to be down when the webhook sends the order?
- could you explain what you mean by the note_attributes bit? It seems to me that step 3 just wouldn't apply with your solution (since I am receiving, not asking for orders)